# Proving constant function given the second derivative.

Tags: calculus

Prove that $f(x)$ is a constant if it has two derivatives and the second derivative is greater  than or equal to 0.

I know that if $f(x) = const$, its 1st derivative should equal 0, but how can it be equal to 0 and increasing??

EDIT: Forgot to add that $f(x)$ is also less than or equal to 0, :D

Comment: $f(x) = x^2$ fulfills both criteria, but is not constant.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that the function is also less than or equal to 0

Answer (score 1):

If the second derivative is non-negative,
the first derivative must be weakly increasing.
It is clear that if $f'(x) \rightarrow a>0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$
imply that $f$ is eventually positive, 
so we can assume that $f'(x)<0$ everywhere.

Now, $f'(x)\rightarrow b\leq 0$ as $x \rightarrow -\infty$,
since $f'$ is increasing. (The case $b=-\infty$ can also be a possibility).

If $b=0$, then the function is constant, and if $b<0$,
then a similar argument as above shows that $f(x) \rightarrow \infty$
as $x \rightarrow -\infty$. This contradicts negativity of $f$,
so $f$ must be a negative constant.

Comment: Can you explain the "eventually positive" part?

Thanks

Comment: Well, for some $X$, we have that $f'(x)\geq a/2$ if $x>X$, (follows from how limits work).
Now, $f$ is just the area under $f'$, from say $X$, plus some constant. But, area under $f'$ from $X$ to infinity is at least the area of a rectangle with height $a/2$ and infinite width, so $f$ must have go to infinity as x does.

Or, you can just argue that $f(x)$ must lie above the line $y=ax/2+c$ for some fixed $c$.

Comment: How does $f'(x) \to 0$ as $x \to -\infty$ imply $f$ is constant? Maybe true, but it should be said why so.

Comment: Well, since we already assumed that $f' \leq 0$ everywhere, and it is also weakly increasing, so if the limit to the left is 0, then the entire f' is at least 0, but at the same time, it is at most 0. Thus, constant.

Comment: Makes sense. And +1...